# Pandas assigning value with list-like indexer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean, mask

I have a question that was already treated in 2014: [See @jeff answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23227171/assignment-to-containers-in-pandas). However I would like to know if things evolved since.

I wrote a code that worked for me but didn't for a colleague:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["yes", "no", "yes", "no"], 'B': [1,2,1,3]})

    A   B
0   yes 1
1   no  2
2   yes 1
3   no  3

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [7,5,9,4], 'B': [4,4,4,4]})

    A   B
0   7   4
1   5   4
2   9   4
3   4   4


df[df2["A"] == "yes"]  = np.full(2, 20.0) * df.values[2]
```

This works perfectly find for me and gives me the desired output:

```
    A   B
0   180 80
1   5   4
2   180 80
3   4   4
```

However it returns an error to my colleague:

```
ValueError: cannot set using a list-like indexer with a different length than the value
```

And this is what @Jeff described in his answer ["Bottom line, don't use lists inside of a pandas object. Its not efficient, and just makes interpretation difficult / impossible."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23227171/assignment-to-containers-in-pandas)

Was there any changes in pandas that now allow this way of coding? I didnt find anything in the documentation that warns against this possible wrong interpretation.

If this is still a bad practice what does the best practice say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think the answer you are citing is relevant to your problem. Here you are assigning an np.array of shape `(2,)`:

```
(np.full(2, 20.0) * df.values[2]).shape
```

to an np array of shape `(2,2)`:

```
(df[df2["A"] == "yes"]).shape
```

which is handled perfectly well by numpy broadcasting rules. @Jeff answer is about plain lists

so I think your colleague just needs to upgrade either pandas or numpy or both. You can check versions (in terminal) via eg

```
pip show pandas
pip show numpy
```

or in Jupyter notebook via

```
!pip show pandas
!pip show numpy
```

your code works in the recent versions (for me pandas 1.2.2 and numpy 1.19.5